# Writing integer 7 as a character "007" in R

Tags: r, format, number-formatting

I am trying to convert integer into string by using `as.character` function in R. But I need the string to be always of length 3. So `7` will get converted into `007`, `10` into `010` and so on. I am wondering if there is some simple modification of `as.character` (or any other built-in R routine) which will quickly accomplish this.

Comment: If you think any answer is correct, please mark it by clicking the grey check mark - it should turn green.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

See `?sprintf`:

```
R> sprintf("%03d", c(7, 10))
[1] "007" "010"
```

Comment: This is why is absolutely love SO. Thanks.

Comment: Love = Mark it as an answer

Answer (score 7):

Another possibility:

```
formatC(c(7, 10), width=3, flag="0")
# [1] "007" "010"
```

Comment: I missed the `C` in `formatC` at first glance... had been trying to do this with just-plain `format`.